# When defining a foreign key in this Oracle example, what is the significance of the CONSTRAINT keyword?

Tags: oracle

In the code below, The first column I create for the table `courses` is a column called `department_code`. I then define `fk_courses_department_code` and specify that `department_code` in this table will be a foreign key that will reference `department_code` from the `departments` table. What is the relevance, or significance of the `CONSTRAINT fk_courses_department_code` line? As far as I'm concerned, it is understood that `department_code` is a foreign key in this table. What exactly is the role of `fk_courses_department_code` then? Does it even exist as a real column? Is it just an alias for `department_code`? What is it, exactly?

```
CREATE TABLE courses
(
  department_code    VARCHAR2(2)   NOT NULL,
  course_number      NUMBER(3,0)   NOT NULL,
  course_title       VARCHAR2(64)  NOT NULL,
  course_description VARCHAR2(512) NOT NULL,
  credits            NUMBER(3,1)   NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_courses
    PRIMARY KEY (department_code, course_number),
  CONSTRAINT fk_courses_department_code
      FOREIGN KEY (department_code)
      REFERENCES departments (department_code),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What exactly is the role of `fk_courses_department_code` then?*

It is the *name* of the constraint.

This is useful to e.g. drop the constraint later, as that can only be done by supplying the name.

Comment: Awesome! now it makes sense. Can you give an example of how I may drop this specific constraint in the future? And does dropping the constraint mean that I am dropping the "FK" attribute on department_code? Thank you!

Comment: If you don't give it a name, Oracle (kindly... ahem...) does this for you - and you get lovely messages like ".... CONSTRAINT SYS00000045 has been violated..." - a lot of help that is! :-)

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm for constraints and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#CJAHHIBI fro the ALTER TABLE documentation.  Dropping the constraint will NOT remove the referenced attribute.